# Remove html node created with javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I want to preload css background images via creating fake ones that will hold src until the actual image is cached.

How do I remove `preloaderImg` elements that was created before? Do I need to remove them to prevent memory leaks or browser will handle this?

```
let preloaderImg = document.createElement("img");
preloaderImg.src = this.finalSrc;
let subscription = fromEvent(preloaderImg, 'load').subscribe((event: Event) => {
    this.removeClass("loading");
    this.addClass("loaded");
    this.setBackgroundImage(this.finalSrc);
    subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```

Comment: You can set `preloaderImg` to `null` after you unsubscribe. That will set it up for garbage collection in the future.

Comment: @RandyCasburn setting to null will be enough? I've read the object will be kept in memory until there still is some pointer to the object, but I have no idea how to hadle this

Comment: What you've read is that as long as there is any reference to an object, it will be held in memory. This is the nature of closures and how they work. As soon as all references to the object are removed, then the object will be garbage collected (eventually). Since this is the only place you reference that variable, you are assured that it will be garbage collected after you set it to null (on each iteration).

Comment: @RandyCasburn sounds reasonable, can you please post your solution so I will accept it

Comment: @RandyCasburn is spot on.  Setting an object to null will remove reference and ensure gc.

Comment: @godblessstrawberry - done and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `preloaderImg` to `null` after you unsubscribe. That will set it up for garbage collection in the future.

What you've read is that as long as there is any reference to an object, it will be held in memory. This is the nature of closures and how they work. As soon as all references to the object are removed, then the object will be garbage collected (eventually). Since this is the only place you reference that variable, you are assured that it will be garbage collected after you set it to null (on each iteration).